# Resources to study climate models and the stability of solutions to differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am currently taking a course on the mathematical models of climate change, and we are studying from a book called "Mathematics & Climate" by Kaper & Engler, and these two papers:

- [UMAPclimate.pdf](https://www2.oberlin.edu/math/faculty/walsh/UMAPclimate.pdf)
- [WalshStommel.pdf](https://www2.oberlin.edu/math/faculty/walsh/WalshStommel.pdf)

While these two papers are not super hard to read, they are a bit advanced for my level. Same goes for the book as well. I took an introductory course on differential equations, but it was all about how to solve them. We didn't really talk about the solutions themselves. And a big chunk of this paper is about stability of the solutions -- or at least that's what my professor is focusing on. We covered stuff like Lipschitz Condition, asymptotic stability, Lyapunov stability, and the Adomian decomposition method -- all of which seem completely foreign to me and a bit advanced.

Is there a textbook or a course somewhere that explains at least some of these topics in a more beginner-friendly way and/or in a bit more detail?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!